# How can I set customvalidity to have a Link in it?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a customvalidity function for when a username or email are taken, and I want to give the user the option to go to signin from there. Is this possible?

I have tried creating an object for the Link object, from react-router dom, but it eiter doesn't come up when added with a comma, or comes back object object when inserted with a plus sign. I want the email taken notification to have the link in it so the user can click on login directly.

```
        handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const EmailField = document.getElementById('email'); 
        const userField = document.getElementById('username');
        const signinRedirect = <Link to='/signin'> login </Link>;
        const newUser = {
            username : this.state.username, 
            email : this.state.email, 
            password : this.state.password, 
            confirmPassword : this.state.confirmPassword, 
        }; 
        //check passwords match before submitting
        if (this.state.passwordsMatch) {
            let url = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0] === 'localhost' ?  'http://localhost:3306' : 'https://petsosbackend.apps.nonprod-mpn.ro11.allstate.com';
            try {
            await axios.post(url + '/register', newUser)
            .then(res=> {
              if (res.status===202) {
                this.props.history.push('/registersuccess');
                //if email is taken
              } else if (res.data==='email'){                
              EmailField.setCustomValidity('Email address is in use, please select another or '+ {signinRedirect}); 
                EmailField.reportValidity();
                //if name is taken       
              } else if (res.data==='name') {       
                userField.setCustomValidity('Username is in use, please select another or' + signinRedirect); 
                userField.reportValidity();
              }
            })            
            } catch(error) { 

              console.log("Catch = ", error.response); 


            }
        }

    }
```

There is more logic obviously but think these are the two key parts and just need help figuring out how to have the signinRedirect appear in the validity warning.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Principle:

```
 return (
      <div className="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={handleChange} />
        {isEmailInUse && (
          <div className="error">
            Email address is in use, please select another or <Link to='/signin'>Sign in</Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

You are trying to use native messages in a JSX validation method. So you can not do.

JSX has nothing to do with HTML, besides being a way of describing the structure of a document and a similar syntax.

[JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Just do not use native error reporting. Use your own solutions, like the ones I gave in the answer.

You are also working incorrectly with DOM elements. In React, it is common practice to use Ref API or monitored components.

And whenever possible, there should be no conditions in the code like:

```
window.location.hostname.split('.')[0] === 'localhost'
```

For such tasks there are env variables and configurations. You can set BASE_URL and use different values for different modes.

Comment: Do I use this in the const? Not really too sure where to put this logic?

Comment: I've updated the main section to contain the entire method. I want the warning that the email is taken to include a Link to another page, or an a tag if that's more feasible. Is it possible to have JSX or html in the validation string?